# TypeScript definition for pluck

Tags: typescript

The [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) gives the following example for defining a `pluck` function, using "index types" (slightly modified):

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): T[K] {
  return o[name];
}
```

which is obviously called as

```
pluck({a: 1}, 'a')
```

However, I want to define a `pluck` which takes just a property name, and yields a function I can apply to an object to obtain that property, as in

```
const getA = pluck('a');
getA({a: 1})
```

I tried the following:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(p: K) {
  return function(o: T): T[K] {
    return o[p];
  };
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to use it:

```
const a = {a: 1};
const getA = pluck('a');
console.log(getA(a));
```

I get the error

> Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. [2345]

on the line where I call `pluck('a')`. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by moving `T` type definition into inner function and defining constraint for it:

```
function pluck<KeyType extends string>(p: KeyType) {
  return function <T extends Record<KeyType, any>>(o: T): T[KeyType] {
    return o[p];
  };
}

const getA = pluck('a');

const a = { a: 1 };
console.log(getA(a));

const b = { b: 1 };
console.log(getA(b)); //error
```